# Why are there extra resistors in this op-amp circuit?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator

I am trying to replace the LM4250 with a newer op-amp. My take on this circuit is that the op-amp is configured as a unity gain voltage follower that drives a push-pull amplifier to provide the voltage from the trimmer R1.

[image]

What I don't understand is R3, R4 and R5.

Comment: @PeteW that is an incorrect guess. R4 is to protect the op-amp's pin 2 (by current limiting) any voltage excursions on the circuit output exceeding the actual rail voltages of the op-amp (reduced by the resistors R5 and R3).

Comment: @PeteW Yet another example of why you should _not_ write your answers in the comment section. Your answer is now the first thing a visitor to the site reads - just below the question.

Comment: The late Jim Williams wrote about the current booster in AN18.  Figure 2.  That circuit has an LT1010 buffer with more output capability so Sziklai pairs aren't needed.  Also it has a gain of 2.  https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an18f.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To understand this circuit, you have to imagine the push-pull transistor pair at the pins 7, 6, 4 inside the OP-AMP. It uses the supply pins of the OP-AMP as inverted dual-outputs to simplify the next driver stage.

*It's a hack.*

Replacing the OP-AMP for another type requires thorough testing because this kind of circuit *is a hack.*

Comment: That explains why I found this circuit confusing; I was thinking of pins 4/7 as strictly inputs.

Comment: Tip: "op-amp" is an abbreviation of "operational amplifier". It's not an initialisation, acronym or proper noun so it doesn't get capitalised or all-caps.

Answer (score 7):

---

***Amendment:***

Andy aka has pointed out that the input bias current is so small that my inital thought about R4 is incorrect. I stated, wrongly, that:

> R4 is to balance the opamp's input bias currents, as explained in this
> article:
> [Opamp input bias current compensation](https://www.daenotes.com/electronics/devices-circuits/operational-amplifier-bias-current-compensation-method#sthash.UyXTMmU3.dpbs)

I agree with Andy aka, but I'm not yet sure how R4 could protect the opamp's input from voltages at the output that exceed its acceptable input range. Thus I am unable to say anything about what R4 actually does, except that Andy aka's idea of protecting the opamp input is more likely than mine.

---

To understand the roles of R3 and R5, start by understanding the output stage of a typical opamp, in particular what happens when an opamp is sourcing current to a load, and how that changes when it is sinking current from the load.

When the load connected to an opamp's output is trying to "pull down" that output to some lower potential, then the opamp's upper output transistor (Q1 in my diagram below) will switch on in an attempt to counter this. The opamp output is said to be sourcing current. The key point to realise is that all this extra current comes in via the opamp's positive supply terminal:

[image]

If, however, the load is attempting to "pull up" the output potential, the opamp counters by switching on Q2 instead. In that scenario, current now enters the output, and the opamp is said to be sinking current. Again, the key thing to notice is that this "sunk" current now emerges from the opamp's negative power terminal:

[image]

Referring now to your schematic, the two resistors R3 and R5 are sat squarely in the path of any current (over and above its normal operating current) that the opamp is sourcing or sinking via its output.

You should also notice that these resistors are connected directly across the base-emitter junctions of their respective transistor, Q1 or Q2, and this means that the voltage across R3 or R5 is capped at around 0.7V. The opamp's supply voltage is therefore reduced a little (1.4V or so), but not much.

Now consider what happens when the opamp wants to raise its output voltage, in opposition to the influence of whatever load is connected there. It begins to source current from its output, current which must originate from its positive supply, via R5. The increased current in R5 causes the voltage across it to rise, crucially, switching on Q1 harder (and consequently also Q3. Note that Q1 and Q3 form an extremely high gain PNP "Sziklai pair"). Together Q1 and Q3 become more conductive, taking over the role of raising output potential, and alleviating the opamp of any high current demand.

In fact, that Sziklai pair takes on almost all of the effort of "pulling up" the output voltage, and the opamp has to make very little effort at all.

A similar arrangement, in the form of R3 and an NPN Sziklai pair, takes care of the situation where the opamp needs to sink current from the load.

In summary, then, with this combination of opamp power supply "current sense" resistors, and Sziklai pairs to respond to the sensed current, the opamp's limited output current ability is boosted. The result is an output voltage which is stable and well regulated by the opamp, but is also able to cater for heavy loads that either sink or source current, in spite of the opamp's weak output.

Comment: If output is pulled down, you said that Q1 is turned on but Q2 should also be turned on. 
To make the output reduces, Q2 should win. How would you explain this? Why Q1 is finally turned on in this case?

Comment: @anhnha Not sure what you mean. Who's pulling the output low? The load, I assume you mean. In which case Q1 turns on as the opamp draws current from the positive supply to counter the load's effect. Q2 won't be affected by that. The only thing that can turn Q2 on is an increased current out of the opamp negative supply pin, which is not happening here.

Comment: If output voltage reduces then Q1 should be off and Q2 on. Q1 cannot source current like you said?

Comment: @anhnha I think you are confusing who's pulling down and who's pulling up. There are two ways the output can fall. If Q2 pulls it down, or the load pulls it down. If the load pulls down, Q1 pulls up. if the load pulls up, then Q2 pulls down.

Comment: Isn't the load passive component like speaker so it cannot control Q1, Q2?

Comment: Read the data sheet on bias current, compare the error produced with the normal offset voltage error and, you should realize that R4 brings nothing to the party regards your ill-placed hunch. Also read note 2 on the data sheet and carefully study the circuit and you will realize that R4 is to protect pin 2.

Comment: @anhnha Whatever the load is, it's disturbing the ouput. That disturbance is fed back via R4 to form negative feedback. That negative feedback causes the opamp to correct the disurbance. It's as simple as that. All Q1 and Q2 do is react to the opamp's struggle to correct the output (by sensing changes in its current demands) and assist by pushing or pulling the ouput in the same direction the opamp is trying (and would otherwise fail) to do.

Comment: @anhnha I don't consider the nature of the load to be relevant to this operation. You are right that the load doesn't directly control Q1 or Q2, but its effect on the output causes the system to react. The road doesn't control you, but you react to how it bends left and right as you drive, to keep yourself central in the lane.

Comment: This is a power supply circuit that drives the active termination of an S100 bus backplane. The load is a slew of TTL level data lines (96) driven through a 270Ω current limiting resistor and 12 47μF filter capacitors.  While in theory, all the lines could be in the same state, I'd say that a 50% is more likely.

Not sure if that helps clarify things.

Comment: @LeeMorgan OK! I had to look up S100, but yes, I think I see what the purpose is. The requirement is for an extremely low impedance "5V÷2 return point" for multiple signal transmission line termination resistors to "ground at". Does that sound right?

Comment: OK, you have a point, @Andyaka , I will amend my answer to address this.

Comment: @SimonFitch That is my understanding. The page of the board I'm building is here http://www.s100computers.com/My%20System%20Pages/S100%20Motherboard/S100%20Motherboard.htm

I got the wrong number of capacitors (that's what I get for posting late from memory)

What makes this circuit complicated from my perspective is the noise is in the 10+MHz range.

Answer (score 5):

> *What I don't understand is R3, R4 and R5.*

It's a rather specialist circuit and will only work on previously tested configurations hence, if you are replacing the op-amp, test it carefully and thoroughly.

- R4 prevents an over-voltage situation on pin 2 of the op-amp
- R3 and R5 are part of the specialist circuit that biases and drives the output transistors rather than using the op-amp output to directly drive the base of a BJT.
- **R2** on pin 8 makes this a non-standard op-amp circuit and finding a replacement will be more than a stroll in the park.

---

[image]

It has been mentioned in a comment (see above) that R4 is to reduce input bias current errors but this is incorrect. The maximum input bias current for the chip is 80 nA (worst case across temperature) and, if R4 was omitted, we would see a maximum input voltage error of 80 nA multiplied by the effective resistance at the non-inverting input. That resistance will be worst case 1400 Ω hence, the worst case error would be (1400 x 80) nV = 112 μV.

**Considering that the normal offset voltage of the op-amp can be in the range +/- 6000 μV, suggesting that R4 reduces input bias current errors is a preposterous thing to say.**

Going back to my point about it protecting the input circuits consider this; the supply voltage to the op-amp is not the full supply rail of 8 volts and ground (ref the OP's circuit diagram); it is somewhat reduced by the two resistors R3 and R5. However, the output voltage can reach to about 0.7 volts of either power rail and, it's likely that without R4 the voltage reaching the input will exceed (a little bit) the voltage at the op-amp power rails. Given this statement in the [data sheet](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/engr/engr40m.1178/labs/lm4250.pdf): -

[image]

It is no-surprise that R4 is used to protect the input on pin 2.

---

There might also be another issue associated with this circuit and that is due to the op-amp output being directly tied to the circuit output. I'd be tempted to place a small resistor in series with the output as shown here in red: -

[image]

It doesn't need to be more than a few tens of ohms and, it can be easily made to be zero ohms if it is found not to be required. However, if you look at the data sheet (page 9), there appears to be a 100 ohm resistor internal to the device but, given that the op-amp output may become forced higher than its supply rails, on the same basis as using R4 to protect pin 2, it's worth the extra small investment in circuitry (especially if you are trying to find a replacement op-amp).

Comment: R4 isn't doing that at all. The high input resistance of the opamp ensures that whatever appears at the opamp's output also appears at its input. R4 is to balance input bias currents.

Comment: @SimonFitch I strongly suggest you analyse the circuit more thoroughly and read the data sheet. You are of course incorrect.

Comment: Minor firefight moved to chat. I was surprised at the flags received. The system does not allow them to be declined AND answered, sadly. [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129494/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-why-are-there-extra-resistors-in-this-op-amp-ci).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I'd push all of the comments into chat. The very presence of the first comment has probably misled several folk already (judging by the comment upvote quantity).

Comment: @Andyaka  Balancing act, as often :-(. The 1st two comments above are technical and so usefulish. I TRY to minimise interaction with people's input. I'll edit your above comment and take out the non technical part. It remains in the char version. IF you wish to remove the comment please do so and tell me and I'll delete Simon's one. All comments are still present in chat.

Comment: Don’t bite my head off please, but I don’t buy the over-voltage theory. Pin 6 (and therefore pin 2) is firmly regulated to 2.7V during normal operation – it’s not going anywhere. Worst case: power down, pin 6 and 2 held at 2.7V by huge capacitance. Looking at internal schematic of LM4250 it’s clear 2.7V on input pin will not hurt anything, even if power rails are at zero. There’s already a 10K resistor in base-emitter path so adding 1K at the base is negligible, regardless. Suspect designer just put in R4 out of habit to address a non-existent bias compensation problem.

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the “2.65 to 2.70V” note on the output node, this circuit appears to be a 2.7V power supply, trimmable to the desired voltage with R1.

R3 and R5 are inline with the opamp rails and also across base emitter junctions of Q1 and Q2.
For Q1 (or Q2) to do anything at all there must be at least 0.6V across R5 (or R3). At 560 ohms that would be 1mA flowing through it.

So, for output loads up the 1mA the opamp will supply all the necessary current to the load.

Beyond 1mA, the opamp will start pulling enough current through R3 (or R5) that the transistors will start turning on, at which point they supply the bulk of the required current load. The opamp never has to supply much more than a mA no matter the load.

The LM4250 is a funky specialized opamp with an extra “biasing” input pin 8, and an R2 value of 150K appears to set a nominal supply current of something in the neighborhood of 50uA if I’m extrapolating the datasheet correctly. Not sure why/if that was a particularly critical parameter.

The addition of R4 is questionable. As others have pointed out, a resistor there is sometimes used to balance the DC offset from the bias currents flowing from the opamp inputs. But here we have a trimpot to finely adjust the output, so any offset will be nulled with that. And the output voltage level is fixed at 2.7V so there’s no chance of overvoltage (barring some external hookup mishap).

Replacing the LM4250 with another opamp may work OK, but the circuit depends on the nominal power supply current draw. Typical opamps can draw 1mA or more so you may find your transistors turn on with no load which may not be what you want. If that’s the case just reduce the values of R3 and R5 so it takes more current before the transistors turn on.

Answer (score 3):

R4 may balance input offset caused by the op amp's input bias current and the non-zero source resistance that is R1, R9, and R10.

Regarding R3 and R5, they are used together with Q1/Q2 and the class B output stage of the op amp to create a [Sziklai pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sziklai_pair) (aka compound pair) for greater output current capability. The Sziklai pair may function without them, but they help Q1/Q2 turn off faster.

Q3/Q4 follow the Sziklai pair for even more current gain.

Comment: R4 is **NOT USED** to balance input bias current errors. It's used to protect pin 2 as I have had to explain in my answer.